# spring-boot-starter-web-reactive + spring-boot-starter-actuator doesn't work together?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-webflux

I tried out spring-boot-starter-actuator, by default instructions, add to spring boot project in pom, and it works without any issues.

As soon as I add spring-boot-starter-web-reactive everything breaks down, newly created reactive endpoint works, but actuator stopped working, have anybody had such issue and maybe already have any ideas how to solve it?
Also noticed, that h2 /console which I had working before, also broken.

I receive no errors, no exceptions, these things just stop working.

Answer (score 1):

As Github page of Spring Boot Web Reactive Starter mentiones:

> This **experimental** project ...

and

> Go to start.spring.io, set the Spring Boot version to **2.0.0(SNAPSHOT)** and add the "Reactive Web" starter.

When it's experimental, it is clearly not meant to be used in production and is not fully stable. Feel free to contribute or create issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please, refer to this post [Netty HttpServer api changed/differs from available examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40830340/netty-httpserver-api-changed-differs-from-available-examples/40875809#40875809)
As the reactive-web is experimental you should add BOM file with compatible versions of libraries.